# OrientDB Unable to execute SQL script in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I tried to run simple script but somehow it doesn't work. Not sure if this is with latest snapshots or something.

Here is the script.

```
script SQL
CREATE CLASS Person extends V;
CREATE VERTEX Person set name="Luca";
LET $a = (MATCH {class:Person, as:s} RETURN s);
select expand($a.s);
end
```

Here is the output, I don't understand why it should fail. other thing is that the error is thrice instead of once, so there is something missing here. I am using latest snapshots of orientdb 3.0

```
orientdb {db=demo}> script SQL
[Started multi-line command. Type just 'end' to finish and execute]

Error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
CREATE CLASS Person extends V;

+----+------------+---------+
|#   |operation   |className|
+----+------------+---------+
|0   |create class|Person   |
+----+------------+---------+
Server side script executed in 0.070000 sec(s). Returned 1 recordsCREATE 
VERTEX Person set name="Luca";
LET $a = (MATCH {class:Person, as:s} RETURN s);
select expand($a.s);
end
Error: 
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class Person already exists
    DB name="demo"
    DB name="demo"

 Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class Person already exists
    DB name="demo"
    DB name="demo"

 Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class Person already exists
    DB name="demo"
    DB name="demo"

  Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class Person already exists
    DB name="demo"
    DB name="demo"
```

Comment: I don't understand why this gets multiple vertices created with single create stmt, `script SQL
    CREATE VERTEX Person set name="Luca";
    LET $a = (MATCH {class:Person, as:s} RETURN s);
    select expand($a.s);
   end`

Comment: How are you executing it? copy/paste in console or from a script file?

Comment: @LuigiDell'Aquila using `load script script.sql`, after connectng to db via console, works fine; I get same errors copy/pasting in the console

Comment: @LuigiDell'Aquila, yes I was doing copy paste into console, when executed in java and through console I had similar results.

Comment: @HarinathMallepally could you please open an issue on github? Thanks

Comment: Yes, opened it.

Comment: @HarinathMallepally Please share the issue Link of Github. What was the fix for the same? In my case, if I retry the issue is resolved on restart.